# Change color on text in navigation bar when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on a script, the problem I am having is that the color on the navigation bar when its active, how do I change it to for example white?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkLPG/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" /> Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/temperatur.png" /> Måling</span></a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span><img src="images/sol.png" /> Dagvakt</span></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#"><img src="images/kveld.png" /> Kveldsvakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/vaske.png" /> Kontroll CM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/søk.png" /> Søk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/top2.png" /> Statistikk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/top3.png" /> Rapport</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   $('li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

**CSS**

```
Refer to JSFIDDLE, there's a lot of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you will need is a CSS modification for this, see below commented area for where to make the changes!

```
 li.active a{
 color:white;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 background-color:#ffffff; /*EDIT THIS FOR COLOUR */
 color:#ffffff;
 }
```

Right now the active page will be coloured white as i have modified the hex value (#FFFFFF).

Answer (score 1):

change this part of the css:

```
li.active a{
color:white;
text-transform:uppercase;
background-color:#009900;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

to this (for white background):

```
 li.active a{
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#ffffff;
    }
```

EDIT: sry I altered the hover instead of active the first time...

Answer (score 1):

change background color to #fff

```
li.active a{
color:white;
text-transform:uppercase;
background-color:#fff;
color:#ffffff;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have used the `:active` selector, you may also go for the `:focus` selector. You don't need JS for this use case.

```
ul#nav > li.active > a,
ul#nav > li > a:active,
ul#nav > li > a:focus
{
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color:#009900;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkLPG/4/

you can apply active state by giving a `<li>` the class `.active` or when the user is clicking on an element.

If you want to get rid of default active elements you can stick with your JS: http://jsfiddle.net/EkLPG/6/